# Comparing Patrick Billingsley's Aniversary Edition to previous editions, and to Robert B. Ash's book.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm reading some of the reviews at amazon to the Anniversary edition of Billingsley's 'Probability and Measure', and several users state that the book is riddled with new typos, and plain errors, inexistent in previous editions.

Is this true? Are these problematic for someone who intends to use the book for self-study?

Also, I've read some good reviews on Robert Ash's 'Probability & Measure Theory'. Is this book self-contained, or does it also refer to Billingsley? Does it misses out on some important aspect?

Usually most books that use measure/probability theory eventually refer to Billingsley's book, and so I'm left wondering which one is better. I've read previously [Capinsky's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Integral-Probability-Springer-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/1852337818/ref=pd_sim_14_4?ie=UTF8&dpID=510qv0TN49L&dpSrc=sims&preST=_AC_UL160_SR121%2C160_&refRID=KDDWPCPHQ3NGWT1FKEDZ) and I've had no difficulty in understanding everything. In fact, I thought that the book took too much freedom in some parts.

I'm asking this question because both books Bill and Ash are really expensive, and one much more than the other. So, I would really like to be sure that I'll not be wasting my precious money...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ash's books are free: http://ce.esalq.usp.br/arquivos/aulas/2011/LCE5866/ebooksclub.org__Probability__amp__Measure_Theory__Second_Edition.pdf

Comment: Many Thanks @Bey ;)